# Sprintf with pointers, constants and string formatting

Tags: c, pointers, printf, argv, argc

I am new to C and I have had trouble simplifying this program. I am trying to initalize `name` *once* and `strcat` `name` to `command` *once*. It is a command line executable that takes two args and one optional arg for the filename "new py" or "new txt", or "new py script". I run Windows's MinGW to compile.

Is there a type to allow storage of argv value and a string constant with one line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char command[100] = "cd . > ";
    char *type = argv[1];
    char * name;
    strcat(command,"\"");
    if (argc == 3) {
        char * name = argv[2];
        //strcat(command,name);
    } else {
        char name[20];
        sprintf(name,"new %s file",type);
        //strcat(command,str);
    }
    strcat(command,name);
    strcat(command,".");
    strcat(command,type);
    strcat(command,"\"");
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char * name = argv[2];` and `char name[20];` are in local scope of if-else block. fix example : `char name[20]; if(argc == 3){ strcpy(name, argv[2]); } else   { sprintf(name,"new %s file",type); }  strcat(command, name);`

Comment: Thank you. It's fixed for now. Do you think I could `sprintf` the rest of the command instead of strcats?

Comment: Either in your favorite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy), my block needs to include "`char name[20]; if(argc == 3){ strcpy(name, argv[2]); } else { sprintf(name,"new %s file",type); } strcat(command, name);`". After those changes, I converted all of the `strcat`s to *one* `sprinf`.

My previous understanding of storing `argv` items was that char pointers were needed for compilation because args wouldn't be defined. They are not needed any more because of the initialization of `name`.

My now condensed code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char command[100];
    char * type = argv[1];
    char name[50];
    if (argc == 3) {
        strcpy(name, argv[2]);
    } else {
        sprintf(name,"new %s file",type);
    }
    sprintf(command,"cd . > \"%s.%s\"",name,type);
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Again, thank you [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) for clearing my misunderstanding.

Comment: Note that horrible things can happen if `name` or `type` contains a `"`. Make sure these things only come from fully trusted sources that are aware of this program's limitations.

Comment: Note: for enhanced sanity, use `snprintf()`